# How to Achieve Centered Selected tab in scrollable tab bar -Flutter

Tags: flutter, tabs, tabbar

Thank you in advance for the help. I am new to flutter and trying to achieve this tab look and behavior. Each tab at what ever position must move to the center when selected
[Tab image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFsj9.png)

[Tab image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYg0S.png)